# What is the mass of the following object?

Tags: calculus

The density of the object is $\rho(x,y,z) = z$. The object is in the following range:

$V =${$ {(x,y,z)|  x^2 +y^2+z^2 \leq 2, z\geq 0 , x^2+y^2 \geq1}$}

I am aware the object is between a sphere and a cylinder, I tried switching to $\theta, \rho,r$ but The answer was wrong, I know a triple integral of z is required, I'm just not getting the limits correct.
The answer is $\pi /4$.

Here is my attempt, the final integral gives a wrong answer:

[image]

Comment: Please share your working which you say gave you wrong asnwer

Comment: The upper limit for $z$ is wrong. How much is $x^2+y^2$ when $z=\sqrt 2$?

Comment: I see what you mean, that would make it be equal to 0.  I changed it to be 1, now everything worked out.

Comment: Yes. Check if it gives you the right answer.

Comment: I hope you see why it helps to add your work, not just that it is expected but also it can just be a small mistake you may be making which we can correct rather than trying to explain everything that you already know. Also, in future, please try and type in your work / key steps instead of adding an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\sqrt2} \int_1^{\sqrt{2-z^2}} z \ r \ dr \ dz \ d\theta$

But what happens to bounds of $r$ for example, when $z = \sqrt2$?

At intersection of cylinder and sphere,

$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1 + z^2 = 2 \implies z = 1 $

So the integral should be,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \int_1^{\sqrt{2-z^2}} z \ r \ dr \ dz \ d\theta$

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an explicit triple integral, I would divide into horizontal slices. The cross section of your shape at height $z$ is an annulus ("washer") with outer radius of $\sqrt{2-z^2}$ and inner radius of $1$, so its area is $\pi(2-z^2-1)$. Multiply by the density $z$ and integrate over the relevant range of $z$:
$$ \int_0^1 \pi(1-z^2)z\, dz = \pi \left[ \frac{z^2}{2} - \frac{z^4}{4} \right]_0^1 = \frac14 \pi $$

(This is actually the same as your triple integral here, once you fix the limits of the outer integral -- but explaining it geometrically makes it easier to have confidence in the result than blind symbol churning).